# lollipop how to get music & photos on sd

Tags: 5.0-lollipop, sd-card, photos, music

I have Note 3 running android lollipop 5.0
How do I get my music and photos on to the 32Gb sd card?
Note I do not want to move the apps just the data.

Answer (score 1):

I haven't used the *Note 3* but all the Galaxys I have used had the *My files* app preinstalled. So:

1. go to that *Files* app
2. navigate to your music
3. longpress on one of your songs, then click the menu in the corner
4. select "move file" or select all then "move files"
5. navigate to your sd card and hit "paste" from the menu or diplayed botton that says "paste".

If you do not have the *My files* app then download a file manager app. I would recommended *Root explorer* – but if you don't have that either, check with the [list of file managers by Izzy](https://android.izzysoft.de/applists/category/named/file_fileman) and you should find it (and additional candidates) relatively easy.

//thanks to Izzy for making your list of file managers//

Comment: Thanks for recommending my lists, Sean! I was so free to give your post a little polish in return (formatting, spelling) and then countered the downvote it received. Please avoid txtspk on behalf of our non native speakers ;)